# Javascript Object changing from typed element to arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, object

Client Side Javascript scenario: Choosing multiple files in a single window to upload. Storing selected files in:

```
var SelectedFile={};
```

using the element name as a key.  I am pushing elements into the object using:

```
SelectedFile[event.srcElement.name]=event.target.files[0];
```

which is inside a function call. Variable scope of SelectedFile is global to the function.

Inside of this function, all elements of SelectedFile are visible as "File" objects.

When I access SelectedFile from another function, the elements are now "ArrayBuffer" and I have lost all keys and sub-objects within the File instances.

How to I ensure that the elements of "SelectedFile" stay as "File" objects at all times?

```
"use strict";
window.addEventListener("load", Ready);

var SelectedFile={};

function Ready() {
        if(window.File && window.FileReader) {
                document.getElementById('UploadButton').addEventListener('click', StartUpload);

                $(".upreel").each(function(idx,obj) {
                        obj.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                                console.log(event.target.files[0]);
                                SelectedFile[event.srcElement.name]=event.target.files[0];                                    console.log(SelectedFile[event.srcElement.name]);
                                console.log(SelectedFile);
                        });
                });

        } else {
                document.getElementById('UploadArea').innerHTML="Your Browser Doesn't Support The File API. Please Upade Your Browser";
        }
}


var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var FReader;
var Name;

function StartUpload() {
        $(".upreel").each(function (index) {
                console.log(index);
        });
        console.log(SelectedFile);
        for (var a in SelectedFile) {
                console.log(SelectedFile[a]);
        };
        socket.emit('StartMultiple',{SelectedFiles:SelectedFile});
}
```

[image]

Comment: if `var SelectedFile={};` is declared inside the function, then it has new scope local to this function. Remove `var` from this declaration

Comment: It isn't declared inside the first function. I want to keep scope global to both functions so I can access the variable from the second one unchanged.

Comment: removing var from the declaration causes an exception to be thrown.

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Comment: why is this tagged node.js if you start off saying it's a client side javascript scenario?

Comment: my bad. It's a javascript front-end interface but a nodejs backed.

Comment: when removing var from the declaration, a ReferenceError is thrown.

Comment: are you using `strict mode`?

Comment: Can you add your code? because we can guess whole day

Comment: It kind of *sounds* like **SelectedFile** is getting clobbered someplace else in your code.

Comment: yes I am using strict mode.

Comment: SelectedFile isn't being used (yet) other than in these two functions.
Code added.

Comment: console log added.

Comment: anyone got any ideas ? I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try with different browsers by any chance? I tried your code (slightly changed) on my chrome and it works perfectly

Comment: Things are definitely not consistent. I'm using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.87 on OSX. Just ran the code again. At the end of "function Ready()" I see a "file" in the SelectedFile object, but as soon as I hit "Upload" it's turned back into an ArrayBuffer again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't seem able to replicate the behaviour here either. Using Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit) under Windows 7.

This code appears to duplicate yours, albeit without the use of jQuery.

Also, I notice that while the console output appears to indicate `SelectedFile` to be an object that contains 2 `ArrayBuffer` members, this is not backed-up by the output of `console.log(SelectedFile[a]);` - I'm not so sure I'd be inclined to think the console output to be correct. If you can still use the objects as expected, I'd be looking for a reason to trust the console over my own observations.

The output I see is identical with the exception of the output of `console.log(SelectedFile);`, which gives the output of `[reelfile1: File, reelfile2: File]` as shown below.

[image]

The code required follows. Ironically enough, when run as a stack-snippet, the output is also incorrect, though is fine when using the native console, rather than the emulated one provided by StackOverflow. For this reason, I'll not post it as a snippet you can run on this page, just save as a new file instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByClass(clss,parent){return (parent==undefined?document:parent).getElementsByClassName(clss)}

// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types (array-like types)
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
let SelectedFile = [];

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    byId('uploadButton').addEventListener('click', onUploadBtnClicked);

    var fileInputs = allByClass('upreel');
    forEach(fileInputs, attachFileInputListener);

    function attachFileInputListener(fileInputElem, index)
    {
        fileInputElem.addEventListener('change', onFileInputChanged, false);
    }
}

function onFileInputChanged(evt)
{
    console.log(this.files[0]);
    SelectedFile[this.name] = this.files[0];
    console.log(SelectedFile);
}

function onUploadBtnClicked(evt)
{
    var fileInputs = allByClass('upreel');
    forEach(fileInputs, showIndex);
    console.log(SelectedFile);
    for (var a in SelectedFile)
    {
        console.log(SelectedFile[a]);
        console.log(SelectedFile[a].name);
    }
    function showIndex(elem, index, array)
    {
        console.log(index);
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' class='upreel' name='reelfile1'/><br>
    <input type='file' class='upreel' name='reelfile2'/><br>
    <hr>
    <div id='UploadArea'></div>
    <hr>
    <button id='uploadButton'>Upload</button>
</body>
</html>
```

TLDR; - There doesn't actually seem to be a problem here, other than the display in the console.

Comment: Further testing shows that after sending this "SelectedFile" object across Socket.io to the server (nodejs) I am seeing "ArrayBuffer" elements arriving at the server. Hence my focus on the client side. If they are "File" elements when they leave, they ought to be "File" elements when they get to the server.

Comment: An interesting observation is that when inspecting the size of the "ArrayBuffer" elements, they exactly match the size of the files that were selected. it's almost as if the "File" element has been replaced by the binary contents of the file itself. I'm not sure by what mechanism this is happening yet, but i will investigate further.

Comment: Hmmm. They are some interesting and odd observations. While I'm reluctant to say it (and apologise if done already) it might just be time to bust-out some extra-strength Mortein for a debugging session, placing a watch on the `SelectedFile` object and stepping through the code to pin down exactly where/when the apparent change happens. Being a global can only help here I suppose.